# wordpress submit form to create and save to database

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have here a regular form the takes an input from the user.

```
<form method="POST" action="/* missing action */">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create/>
</form>
```

Now, as you noticed in the form's attribute `action` is missing. What should I put there to map it in the `functions.php` that I made.

```
function create(firstname, lastname) {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->insert(.....);
}
```

OR if what I thought does not make sense. What should be I put there to save user's input. I hope you'll help me with this. Thanks alot.

EDITED

`functions.php` resides in the theme.

Comment: Where does your `functions.php` reside in your wordpress structure? is it included as part of a plugin or theme?

Comment: Forgot about that. Sorry. It is included in the theme.

Comment: Since it's included in your theme realistically you may not need an action and can post your form to the current path, and handle your output accordingly.